# NullPointerException with LWJGL 3 Initialization

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to setup a new project in IntelliJ using LWJGL version 3. I just tried out this [example](http://www.lwjgl.org/guide): Whenever I try to run it,
I get a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` caused by a `java.lang.NullPointerException` while loading the library.

My natives are in project_root/lib/lwjgl/native/macosx/x64, so my vm argument is:
`-Djava.library.path=lib/lwjgl/native/macosx/x64`
I have also added lwjgl to the classpath.

The stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at test.HelloWorld.execute(HelloWorld.java:18)
    at test.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.loadLibrarySystem(LWJGLUtil.java:326)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:36)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:33)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to specify an *absolute* path for `java.library.path`, rather than a relative one.

On the LWJGL forums, [there was a user with a similar problem](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5552.msg29359#msg29359) (I found this by searching for [the problematic line](https://www.google.com/search?q=org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.loadLibrarySystem(LWJGLUtil.java%3A326)) and doing some hunting on the forum). The relevant part of the conversation is:

> **lightbringer** [writes](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5552.msg29366#msg29366):
>
> I think I figured it out. In LWJGLUtil.java I took out some code and ran it from my main()`. I got an
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: lib/native\lwjgl.dll`
>
> inside loadLibrary(). System.load() apparently needs an absolute path but you are passing it a relative path.
>
> I tested with -Djava.library.path=E:\Dropbox\private\projects\solariad\redist\lib\native and this indeed did work as expected.

---

The root of the issue is LWJGL's use of [`System.load()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)), which is not problematic in itself, but it does requires an absolute path name to the libraries it loads (see [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Runtime.java#Runtime.load0%28java.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.String%29) as well).

If you take a look at [LWJGLUtil.java](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/LWJGLUtil.java) (although the version at the time of this writing does not correspond exactly to your stack trace) and [`Sys.doLoadLibrary()`](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/f760abeb81154ad2976c9879d50500a058150bf1/src/java/org/lwjgl/Sys.java), you can see that it attempts to load libraries by going through all the path strings in `java.library.path`, appending the library name, and trying `System.load()` on those paths. Since `load()` requires an absolute path the implication is that `java.library.path` must contain the absolute path to the LWJGL libraries as well.

It is unfortunate that the root cause of the problem was muddled by the NPE but, you know, it's a hard knock life for us poor programmers!

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! It was drivin me crazy. But why did they change it (because a relative path worked in lwjgl 2)?

Comment: @tobs That I couldn't tell you. The current LWJGL source uses `System.load()` and iterates through the path names in `java.library.path` when searching for the libraries. I do not know what the LWJGL 2 behavior was.